# Question about Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

can someone tel me if i can write : $$
-div(\phi(|\nabla u|)\nabla u)+ \phi(|u|)u =f(u)
$$
like this
$$\sum_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^n, |\alpha|=k}a_{\alpha}(D^{k-1}u(x),...,u(x),x)D^{\alpha}u(x)+G(D^{k-1}u(x),...,u(‌​x),x)=0$$
what is a and G ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Write the divergence term as 
\begin{align*}
  - \operatorname{div}\bigl(\phi(|Du|)Du\bigr) 
  &= \sum_i \phi'(|Du|) \partial_i|Du|\partial_iu 
               + \phi(|Du|)\partial_i^2 u\\
  &= \sum_{i} \phi'(|Du|) \frac 1{|Du|} \sum_j \partial_j u \partial_i u \partial_i\partial_j u + \phi(|Du|)\partial_i^2 u 
\end{align*}
From this we see that $k = 2$, and we have 
\begin{align*}
  a_{e_i+e_j} &= \phi'(|Du|) \frac 1{|Du|} \partial_i u \partial_j u\\
  a_{2e_i} &= \phi'(|Du|) \frac 1{|Du|} \partial_i^2 u + \phi(|Du|) \\
  G &= \phi(|u|)u - f(u)
\end{align*}

Comment: i , j represent $\alpha$ ?

Comment: what is $e_i$, $e_j$ ? please

Comment: $e_i $ and $e_j $ are the unit multiindices, $(0, \ldots, 0,1,0,\ldots,0) $ where the 1 is in the $i $th resp. $j $th spot.

Comment: please how from $\sum_i \phi'(|Du|) \partial_i|Du|\partial_iu 
               + \phi(|Du|)\partial_i^2 u$  you get
  $ \sum_{i} \phi'(|Du|) \frac 1{|Du|} \sum_j \partial_j u \partial_i u \partial_i\partial_j u + \phi(|Du|)\partial_i^2 u$ ?